# Proof of Simple graph using vertex degrees

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, graph-theory

[image]

I think that this graph exists because the Handshaking Lemma says that the sum of the vertex degrees must be an even number. The sum of the vertices is, $1 + 2+3+4+4 = 14$ .  I know that a simple graph is a graph with no loops or multiple edges. I am confused on why this graph does not exist.

Comment: If a graph exists, it's degree sequence follows the handshaking lemma. That doesn't necessarily mean that if a degree sequence follows the handshaking lemma, the graph must exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 5 vertices, and two of them have degree 4, which means that both of them are connected to every other vertex, meaning that every vertex must have a degree of at least 2. So, you cannot have one with degree 1.